# Pass function reference as event handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass function reference as event handler in jQuery. I would like to use a shorthand like in the simple example below...

```
$("a").click(console.debug.bind(undefined,this));
```

...rather than passing explicitly the whole function body:

```
 $("a").click(function() {
     console.debug(this)
 });
```

Moreover, I would like to access elements selected by jQuery in my shorthand function (and pass them as a parameter). In other words: I expect to have a result of `$("a")` as a `this` (or any other code that will retrieve the result).

So far I've tried:

```
var a = function() {
    console.debug(this);
};

var b = console.debug.bind(undefined,this); 

$("a").click(function() {console.debug(this)}); // prints link
$("a").click(a); // prints link 
b(); // prints Window
$("a").click(console.debug.bind(undefined,this)); // prints Window & jQuery.Event
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hbqw2z93/1/

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use such construction and meet all requirements, without definition of additional variables - just one line as shown above?
2. Is it possible to access jQuery's selection result using described approach?
3. Why in the given scope `this` becomes 'merged' Window and jQuery.Event object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You already using it, aren't you? :) It's limited, but it works in your own fiddle
- jQuery will pass event object to your specified function. You can use function bind to pass that as an argument (you already have this working in your fiddle)
- It doesn't. See what's happening:

[jQuery passed one argument](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to click handler function - event object. You pass `console.debug.bind(undefined, this)` as a handler function so jQuery will call it with one argument.

Then, when you are binding [you are asking to use 'undefined'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) as a 'this' object inside the function and sending an extra argument - 'this', which is a Window at this scope because you are binding at the highest level.

So when actual click happens, jQuery calls console.debug with two parameters - Window object that was bound during click() and jQuery event that is always passed to click handler. [console.debug()](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#log) can accept and display multiple objects, which is exactly what you see in the developer console.

Comment: passing undefined is thesame as not passing. it doesn't use undefined as this. also, it's only passing the window to the debug method, `this` is not passed to debug.

Comment: of course 'this' is passed - that's why he is receiving two objects in the console. and comment regarding undefined is just a linguistic abracadabra :) since the function will not have a 'this', it will definitely feel like it has in fact used 'undefined' as 'this' :))

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is the new context to use for `this`. By passing `undefined` you are essentially not passing the first parameter.

The second and further parameters are passed into the function as the first values.

Note also that `this` when in the global scope, refers to the `window` object.

So here, `b`...

```
console.debug.bind(undefined,this);
```

is identical to...

```
function(){ console.debug(window); }
```

..since you're passing `this` (which is `window`) as the first parameter to `debug`.

By default, when you attach an event to the element, `this` will automatically point to the element which caught the event, so bind shouldn't even be necessary, which is why `$("a").click(a);` worked without using bind.